# Detect button press from CLLocationManager Authorization alert

Tags: iphone, ios, uialertview, cllocationmanager

I am detecting whether the user has accepted the request to use location services in my app, I have a toggle switch in the UI that is dependent on this acceptance. The first time they toggle the switch (on) the request to use location is triggered. I want to know which button they press in that alert. (accept or decline) Right now I'm just toggling it off and making the user press it again (then detect which option they picked).

It is kind of sloppy that way, so I'd like to know if there is a way to detect this specific alert or can't that be done since it is triggered by the OS, not the application? I haven't tried it yet, but was thinking I could use the `UIAlertView` delegate methods for just generic button presses, but was hoping for something more specific.

*UPDATE*

I was able to get this working by just registering a notification when I trigger the location request (and the authorization prompt is shown). The application is placed in an inactive state (much like pulling down the notification bar). I just trigger a notification when the application becomes active and I'm able to just query the authorization status there and update my UI. I hope this helps anyone else down the line if they want to handle the authorization status on the fly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way to intercept the alert. There is, however, a method on `CLLocationManagerDelegate` method called [didChangeAuthorizationStatus](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManagerDelegate_Protocol/CLLocationManagerDelegate/CLLocationManagerDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/CLLocationManagerDelegate/locationManager%3adidChangeAuthorizationStatus%3a). That's probably the closest you can get to intercepting the alert.

Comment: That works. I probably should have dug a little deeper to find that one. I think I can make that work. Thanks!

Comment: Solves one problem, but creates another. Lets me catch the change to accept, but if they decline... it hasn't technically changed, so it doesn't do anything for me. The solution is there... just need to figure it out. But I think this is the best answer to go on.

Comment: I recommend triggering based on the delegate method in this answer, and then using the method I gave you to decide the status of the switch.  Pretty straight-forward...

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to know explicitly which button the user selects since, as you've said, this alert comes from the OS.  You can however, find out if location services has been enabled for your app, and know that way.  Use a method such as this:

```
-(BOOL)locationServicesIsEnabled
{
    if (![CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled] || ![CLLocationManager     authorizationStatus])
    return NO;
return YES;
}
```

Comment: As I said, albeit not quite as clear, I am already detecting whether the user has accepted it or not. I just want to intercept the alert so I can update my UI in one action rather than hack it up or make the user toggle the on/off switch twice.

Comment: There is no approved way to intercept it, and I don't know of any hacked (unapproved way).  If you think about the information you want to access, it should be pretty clear to you that there's no way Apple's going to let you do that...  Sorry.

Comment: Definitely not looking for "unapproved" as this app is currently in the App Store. Just looking for a better way. I will have to try the alert delegate... might be able to figure it out that way as my "hack".

Comment: If you think about that, it will not work.  For that to work, your view controller would have to be the delegate for that UIAlertView.  Not only will it NOT be, it CAN'T be, since how would the OS know about your app, much less your view controller to set as delegate.  What you want to do is simply not possible.  Sorry.

Comment: I was able to test out trying to intercept the alert button presses, as we figured, no joy. I did notice that the application gets put into an inactive state when that alert is present. Pressing either button triggers the applicationDidBecomeActive method in the AppDelegate... so I might be able to work around that.